# Having an issue with HTML audio/video

Tags: html, css

basically what I am trying to achieve is this audio player in HTML play the audio and the video when the play button is clicked and vise versa for pause. This is my code.

```
<div style="text-align:center"> 
<img src="img/playpause.jpg" onclick="playPause()">
  <br> 
  <video id="video1" width="1200" >
    <source src="pjds.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="pjds.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Oops, your browser doesn't support me :(
  </video>
</div> 
<script>  
var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1"); 
function playPause() { 
    if (myVideo.paused) 
        myVideo.play(); 
    else 
        myVideo.pause(); 
} 
</script> 
<audio controls>
    <source src="ay.ogg" type="audio/ogg" onclick="playPause()">
    <source src="ay.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: And the problem is what?

Comment: @Nit Erm.. It's not doing so....

Comment: In all browsers? On which OS? Open web developer tools and see if there is some error there.

Comment: what "is not doing"? Does the audio not get controlled, but the video works? You are not controlling the audio tag, you know...

Comment: @thriqon Basically only audio is outputting I want the audio and video to be outputted together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best described by example: http://jsbin.com/zivak/1/edit

I set up a video tag and an audio tag, and a button with `onClick`-binding. For educational purposes I left the controls visible, but they should be hidden as they will tamper with your state.

Upon clicking the button the elements are retrieved from the DOM and then `play()`ed, if paused, and `pause()`, otherwise.

Keep in mind that `onClick` is one-way, so to speak...

---

**UPDATE**: Yes, that is possible, although it will get complicated since both tags might have to buffer indepentently, and you have to take care to synchronize that. It's by no means easy...  but is http://jsbin.com/zivak/4/edit how you thought about it?

---

**UPDATE**: If you mean "mute the audio, leave the video on", then no. If you mean "mute the audio, mute the video", yes, this is actually quite easy: http://jsbin.com/zivak/5/edit .

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is it possible for only one of those audio controls to basically control the video and audio? For example if I play the audio the video will play?

Comment: Thanks for the help! But I just have one more question, for the control volume is it possible to mute the audio not the video? Cheers

Comment: Thriq, is it possible to only have one control for them? not two?

Comment: Also, if this answer solved your problem, I'd be delighted if you could accept it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
     var myVideo = document.querySelector("video1"); 
     if (myVideo.get(0).paused) {
          myVideo.get(0).play();
     }
      else {
          myVideo.get(0).pause();
     }
```